Swing JButton text encoding
I was playing around with Swing, and faced following problem with text encoding with JButton class
So would be grateful for explanation or some links explaining why this code display broken text - 'Р'РёР±СЂР°С, Рё':
JButton selectButton = new JButton("Вибрати");

but when I explicitly specify encoding everything works fine:
JButton selectButton = new JButton(new String("Вибрати".getBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

File with code has UTF-8 encoding

File with code has UTF-8 encoding Are you sure - can you provide a link to it?

IntelliJ IDEA says UTF-8)) Here - https://github.com/momopoi443/sandbox

Yes, it's UTF-8, but what does "doesn't work" mean?

and what is the result of Charset.defaultCharset() ? (the default Charset is used by getBytes()) -- I also wonder what is the result of new String("Вибрати".getBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8) (on your system)

Means it displays broken text "Р'РёР±СЂР°С, Рё", not correct one "Вибрати"

@user85421
default charset is windows-1251
and this code new String("Вибрати".getBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8) gives broken text in console

"the result of Charset.defaultCharset()" IS "windows-1251"?? To be exact, the output of something like System.out.println( Charset.defaultCharset() );

javac -encoding UTF-8 Sanbox.java would probably make a difference

@user85421 I did exactly System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset()); to get it

I see, use the -encoding option as commented by g00se (actually I would change the settings of windows to support UTF-8)

yeap, -encoding UTF-8 works, thanks guys)

new String("Вибрати".getBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8) ← Never do that.  All Java Strings have the same encoding, and it cannot be changed.  That code will only corrupt things further.  You can, however, specify the encoding of your source files at compile time, if you’re certain of the encoding they use.
